# How to display article alphabetically in expression engine

Tags: expressionengine

we want to sort article by alphabetically in expression engine so please guide me how to display article by alphabetically.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at adding the following paramaters to your channel tag:

```
orderby="title" sort="asc"
```

For more information, see the [documentation on this parameter here](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/channel_entries.html#orderby)